# CONCAT created DATE columns to add DATETIME columns

Tags: sql, datetime, casting, google-bigquery, concatenation

Platform: BigQuery

I have created two single MIN and MAX DATE columns (YYYY-MM-DD) from two separate tables. I now want to add an additional column alongside each one by adding a time to them in HH:MM:SS format to create a DATETIME column for both start and end date columns. No time exists, it's just for convention purposes, so the time will be: 00:00:00.

I have tried 'CONCAT(CAST'as DATETIME but it doesn't appear to work for me.
I haven't added my attempt into the below as I'm not sure when, how or where it should go.

**

Below is my current query without the additional columns:

**

````
distinct(table1.person_id),
LEAST(MIN(table1.AssessmentDate),MIN(table2.ContactDate)) visit_start_date,
GREATEST(MAX(table1.AssessmentDate),MAX(table2.ContactDate)) visit_end_date,
FROM `Assessmentsdataset` Assmnt
inner join Contactsdataset` Contacts
ON (
Assmnt.person_id = Contacts.person_id
)
inner join `MASTER.person` mstr_person 
ON (
Assmnt.person_id = MASTER_person.person_id    
)
group BY Assmnt.person_id```

**

 - Desired result would be

**

|person_id|visit_start_date|visit_start_datetime|visit_end_date|visit_end_datetime|
|:--------||:--------------||:------------------||:------------|:-----------------|
|   1234  |   YYYY-MM-DD   |YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00| YYYY-MMMM-DD |YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00|
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want them as `datetimes`, just `cast()` them:

```
CAST(LEAST(MIN(table1.AssessmentDate), MIN(table2.ContactDate)) AS DATETIME)
```

You can also use `DATETIME()`:

```
DATETIME(LEAST(MIN(table1.AssessmentDate), MIN(table2.ContactDate)))
```

Comment: Doh! How didn't I think of that! I was close, but no cigar - thank you very much, that's immediately solved my issue.